# Android TableLayout or GridView?

Tags: android, gridview, fade, tablelayout

I want to create a grid of words approximately three wide and eight deep.  I would like to be able to select some of the words and do a fade animation on them.  I would also like to know when a word has been selected.  I have been looking at TableLayout and GridView to do this.  Would one of these be better than the other to do this?  Is one of them more adaptable to the different screen sizes in Android than the other?

Answer (score 1):

I've played around a bit with tablelayout (and tablerow) and it will definitely do the trick, I guess more importantly the question is whether you expect to have a fixed number of columns or not ("approximately" doesn't help...). If so and you have very good control of what goes in the table/grid, tablelayout may very well be what you're looking for (I just find it simpler, but maybe I'm wrong).

They both can adapt to screen size with the right layout instructions, and proper programming will give you similar results.

But then, if you allow the screen to rotate, you may want to use gridview

parameters, parameters, parameters...

Comment: Thank you for both my answers.  From both answers it seems like the TableLayout will be easier. What are some of the parameters to help adapt the screen size?

Comment: Tablelayout/tablerow automatically spans the width of the parent. what's left for you to do is make sure the elements in the table have a preset columns size: android:stretchColumns or android:layout_weight

Answer (score 1):

I think a `TableLayout` would be more easy to use. For a `GridLayout` you need to build custom adapters and so one which result in a more complicated application.

Looking at different sceensizes, a `GridLayout` will choose a good number of columns and rows by itself according to the content and it will be more flexible with adding items.

Also the `GridLayout` will be more flexible but it is some more work to make.